# ¿Cómo Evitar bucle infinito al usar window.location.reload(true) al iniciar página?

Tags: javascript

Necesito hacer un `window.location.reload(true);` cada vez que inicie la página, pero que no se genere un bucle infinito, porque si lo coloco en una función en el `$(document).ready` o en el `body onload` se repite y repite infinitamente.

¿Cómo podría hacer que se ejecute siempre que inicie la página, esto con el fin de que siempre cargue desde el servidor sin usar la cache, pero solo una vez?

O alguna forma de obtener el mismo resultado (Cargue desde el servidor y no desde cache)...

Es así...

```js
function reload(){
console.log("Se recarga");
window.location.reload(true);  
}
```

```html
<body onload="reload();">
  </body>
```

Comment: Es posible que agregues tu codigo, para poder reproducir el error?

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue, si te das cuenta se crea un bucle infinito y no sé cómo poder hacer para detenerlo.

Comment: *"esto con el fin de que siempre cargue desde el servidor"*. ¿Puedes aclarar esta parte? No entendí el fin si, al fin y al cabo, todo documento HTML es enviado desde el servidor.

Comment: Mira, aquí te explican todo de cómo funciona el `location.reload` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: Sé cómo funciona, lo que no acabo de entender es para qué necesitas hacer ésto. ¿Implementas server side rendering o algo parecido? Curiosidades afuera, puedes guardar una bandera en `sessionStorage` que te indique si el documento aún no ha sido recargado, en ese caso, cambias la bandera y procedes a la recarga. La próxima vez ya no se ejecutará porque la bandera será false.

Comment: @Fabian Montoya, a ver si te entendí. Quieres que la información que se muestra (Html, css, js) en el explorador ¿obtenga siempre del servidor y no del cache?.

Comment: Correcto @Davlio eso es lo que quiero hacer, lo que sucede es que hago cambios en el JS y no los toma hasta que de Ctrl + F5, me dí cuenta que son `location.reload(true)` soluciono ese problema, pero no puedo colocarlo en algún lugar donde me haga ese bucle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiosa pregunta, además de particular. Si no quieres poner el hash que te proponen las otras respuestas, se me ocurre algo con [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

```
let isRedirected = sessionStorage.getItem('isRedirected');
if (!isRedirected) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('isRedirected', true);
  window.location.reload(true);
}
```

**Actualización**

Debido a tu comentario 6 días después de posteada la respuesta, en donde añades otro requisito, el cual consiste en que se debe aplicar a múltiples páginas, edito un poco el código.

Básicamente lo que necesitas añadir es la página a la cual se le ha indicado que haga una recarga forzada al storage:

```
/*
 * Obtenemos la última parte de la URL. Por ejemplo, en una URL como:
 * https://unadireccion.com/blog
 * se obtendrá 'blog'
 */
(function () {
  let page = location.href.substring(location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  let isRedirected = sessionStorage.getItem(page);

  if (!isRedirected) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(page, true);
    window.location.reload(true);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Nunca he manejado eso, y según intento agregarlo no sé como declarar el `isRedirected`

Comment: Solo necesitas copiar y pegar, no hay mayor misterio...

Comment: Eso hice pero me genera un error en el primer `isRedirected` y me dice _Se esperaba ';'_ que raro

Comment: No hay ningún error. Mira [éste fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/wauu1abr/) para que salgas de dudas.

Comment: Si tienes razón, el Visual Studio me genera error por alguna razón pero si funciona, muchas gracias :D

Comment: Este solo me funciona para la primera página, las demás se siguen recargando desde la caché y no lacen el `location.reload(true);` :/

Comment: Has dicho "primera" y "demás páginas". Por lo que **supongo** habrás hecho lo mismo para todas ellas.

Comment: Lo agregue en un archivo .js que utilizan todas las páginas, pero solo funciona en la primera que se carga... ¿qué podría hacer?

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para abordar este nuevo requisito ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, perdón no haber dicho esto, no me habia dado cuenta de que solo estaba funcionando en la primera página hasta el día de ayer...

Comment: No hay problema colega. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hacemos aca es indicar al javascript que la url cambia (Es decir le agregamos un #), siempre y cuando se recargue una vez. Asi evitamos el bucle infinito.

Espero te sirva.

```js
function reload(){

   if(document.URL.indexOf("#") == -1){
       document.URL += '#';
   }

   location = '#';

   console.log("Se recarga");
   location.reload(true);  
}
```

```html
<body onload="reload();">
  </body>
```

Comment: Si te das cuenta, el bucle continua :/  No haces nada, cambias la URL y vuelves a recargar la página

Answer (score 1):

Este ejemplo es copiado al de arriba por  la diferencia es que dentro del primer refresh le coloco el URL y refresco al siguiente ya tendra el # por tanto no se refrescara a la segunda merito para **Ivan Botero**

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("#") == -1){
           document.URL += '#';   location.reload(true);  
       }
    }
```

Comment: Considera agregar un comentario solo por costumbre xD

Comment: Es exactamente que el de arriba, continúa generando el bucle, lo agregué exactamente como lo colocaste

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que agregar [METAs](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html) de control-cache y expiración para el HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Asimismo, tendrías que forzar para los CSS y JS, agregando una versión por ejemplo.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js?v=12392823"></script>
```

[Considere como referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Comment: Ya tengo todo esto, pero sigue sin funcionar, en realidad solo me funciona agregando ese `window.location.reload(true)`

Comment: Es "curioso"... que controles el cache de esa manera. Solo actualicé la referencia.

Comment: Si, tengo todas estas metas agregadas pero no sé, aveces me funcionan y otras no, yo creo que sucedía era lo siguiente, borraba el cache, pero no mantenía el anterior hasta que se recargara la página o no sé, es como si aveces no tomara esas etiquetas